# In C# how to search a text for words in a array and store in a second array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, text, compare

I need to search a text for words in a array and save to a second array efficiently.

```
Example:
string[] myWords = {"Java","CSharp","OO", "and", "mvc"};
string Text = "Both CSharp and Java have mvc frameworks and are OO languages."

Result in Second Array:
  {  "CSharp", "and" , "Java", "mvc", "and", "OO" }
```

Unique words with a count would work too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `efficiently` ? OK, how about showing your inefficent way so that we can work on it to make it more effiicient.

Comment: That's nice. How much are you paying us to write that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is efficient or not but off the top of my head:

```
        List<string> newCollection = new List<string>();
        string[] myWords = { "Java", "CSharp", "OO", "and", "mvc" };
        string Text = "Both CSharp and Java have mvc frameworks and are OO languages.";
        string[] splitText = Text.Split(' ');
        foreach(string s in splitText)
        {
            if (myWords.Contains(s))
                newCollection.Add(s);
        }
```

Or split in the myWords array

```
            List<string> x = new List<string>();
            List<string> newCollection = new List<string>();
            string[] myWords = { "Java have", "CSharp", "OO", "and", "mvc" };

            string Text = "Both CSharp and Java have mvc frameworks and are OO languages.";
            string[] splitText = Text.Split(' ');

            foreach (string s2 in myWords)
            {
                string[] b = s2.Split(' ');
                foreach(string c in b)
                {
                    x.Add(c);
                }
            }

            foreach (string d in splitText)
            {
                if (x.Contains(d))
                {
                    newCollection.Add(d);
                    Console.WriteLine(d);
                }

            }
```

Here is a version that's a little cleaner:

```
List<string> newCollection = new List<string>();
string[] myWords = { "Java have", "CSharp", "OO", "and", "mvc" };

string Text = "Both CSharp and Java have mvc frameworks and are OO languages.";

string[] splitText = Text.Split(' ');

List<string> x = SplitArray(myWords);

foreach (string d in splitText)
{
    if (x.Contains(d))
    {
        newCollection.Add(d);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }

}
```

**function to split the array**

```
public static List<string> SplitArray(string[] strArray)
{
    List<string> rtnArray = new List<string>();
    foreach (string a in strArray)
    {
        string[] x = a.Split(' ');
        foreach(string b in x)
            rtnArray.Add(b);
    }
    return rtnArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This solution works. But would have issues if my array has two words together. Example: string[] myWords = { "Java have", "CSharp and", "OO", "and", "mvc" }; Any suggestions on how to overcome this problem please.

Comment: Same concept...just split on the myWords[] and loop through those values to find matching pairs. I'm not sure where the myWords[] is being generated but I would split on ' ' and add those to the array prior to searching for pairs

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works. I am looping through the words array.    To get the counts and this works too. Can we use Linq to do this?                                                                         foreach (string s in myWords)
                   {
                        if (Text.Contains(s))
                        {
                            if (wordDict.ContainsKey(s))
                                wordDict[s] = wordDict[s] + 1;
                            else
                               wordDict.Add(s, 1);
                        }
                    }

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Dictionary to track the number of instances of each word.
e.g.

```
Dictionary<string, int> wordDict = new Dictionary<string, int> {
    { "Java", 0 },
    { "CSharp", 0 },
    { "OO", 0 },
    { "and", 0 },
    { "mvc", 0 }
};

string text = "Both CSharp and Java have mvc frameworks and are OO languages."
string[] split = text.Split(' ');
foreach(string s in split)
{
    if (wordDict.ContainsKey(s)) {
        wordDict[s] = wordDict[s] + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This solution works. But would have issues if my array has two words together. Example: string[] myWords = { "Java have", "CSharp and", "OO", "and", "mvc" }; Any suggestions on how to overcome this problem please.